# PHP if() state keeps evaluating to true even though it isn't

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I'm having the toughest time figuring out this problem and I can't seem to find the answer.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have different nav menus on my website depending on the section. I've already pre-built the different variations and on each page declare $linkbox_array, which is the array of links for my nav menu on that page. On certain pages I display horizontally and on others vertically. When vertical, I need a disclaimer to be added to the bottom of the stacked link boxes.

So my function is trying to say this: if the $linkbox_array is $general_linkboxes and the $bodyClass is "withSidebar", then echo out a disclaimer after array item 2. Otherwise, just echo out the array items.

So this is what I've written (forgive me if it sucks, I'm new to this):

```
function display_linkboxes($array) {
    if ($linkbox_array == $general_linkboxes && $bodyClass = "withSidebar") {
        foreach ($array as $linkbox) {
            if ($linkbox == $array[2]) {
                echo $linkbox;
                global $general_disclaimer;
                echo $general_disclaimer;
            } else { 
                echo $linkbox;  
            } 
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($array as $linkbox) {
            echo $linkbox;  
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it keeps spitting out the $general_disclaimer even when the two conditions aren't true. I tried to deconstruct the function and figure out where I was going wrong and I realized my if statement always evaluates to true even if I put in jibberish. For example:

```
function display_linkboxes($array) {
    if ($linkbox_array == $askjfdalfjk) {
        foreach ($array as $linkbox) {
            echo $linkbox;
        }
    }
}
```

This evaluates to true and displays the links even though $askjfdalfjk doesn't exist. Then I have the opposite problem below. This won't display the links even though the if statement should evaluate to true:

```
function display_linkboxes($array) {
    if ($bodyClass == "withSidebar") {
        foreach ($array as $linkbox) {
            echo $linkbox;
        }
    }
}
```

What in the world am I doing wrong?!?! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$bodyClass = "withSidebar"` change to `$bodyClass == "withSidebar"`

Comment: the classic **==** vs *=* mistake.

Comment: Some programmers like to write this sort of equality condition with the static element first, like `"withSidebar" == $bodyClass` -- in this case, if you forget and use a single equals, you'll get an error instead of weird behavior.

Comment: Even a half-hearted effort at debugging this yourself would have led you to understand the variables you are testing are not in scope and probably also led you to understand the `=` instead of `==` problem. `$linkbox_array` and `$general_linkboxes` are both `null` so that will always evaluate as true. And you are assigning `withSidebar` to `$bodyClass` so that will always evaluate as true.

Comment: Oh my goodness! It figures it would be something simple like that. But it seems I'm still having problems $bodyClass == "withSidebar evaluating to false. I've updated the function but am not getting the $general_disclaimer even though at the top of the page I declare $bodyClass = "withSidebar"

Comment: @Erick Just changing the `=` to `==` alone will not solve your problem.  You still have the problem of variable scope. Run some `var_dump()`'s on the variable in the conditional and note how they are all null. Again, this is debugging 101.  If you are not getting a conditional coming out the way you think it should... dump the variable and debug it.

Comment: @mike: if only php nulls were like sql nulls and `null == null` would also be null/false.

Comment: @Erick add all values to the function argument if you need, for example: `display_linkboxes($array, $bodyClass, $linkbox_array, $etc){}` then when you call the function simply put the values `display_linkboxes($array, ...);`

Comment: @MikeBrant, I assure that I made a full-hearted effort at figuring this out. But I literally just started learning PHP yesterday (with no prior programming experience).

Comment: @MarcB Yes... if only.  This actually points out another thing here which OP is not doing... validating the data with `isset()` , `empty()`, `!is_null()` or similar.  Ideally the OP would change the code to pass in the necessary variables as parameters and before doing any of the function logic at all, would add variable validation and exit the function appropriately (return false, throw exception, etc.) if the parameters are not of the type and/or values expected.

Comment: @Erick Well welcome to the wonderful world of programming.  You probably learned at least three important pieces of information or areas for further reading.  Variable scope matters (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), comparison operators need to be exact (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php - FYI, I would highly suggest using `===` in most cases), basic troubleshooting tools should be in your tool chest (`var_dump()`, `debug_backtrace()` probably most important among these).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
function display_linkboxes($array) {
    if ($linkbox_array == $general_linkboxes && $bodyClass = "withSidebar") {
...
```

$linkbox_array, $general_linkboxes, and $bodyClass are not in scope for this function, which means they are both equal to each other in that neither of them exists. You need to either pass them as variables to the function (recommended), or change your code to the following:

```
function display_linkboxes($array) {
    global $linkbox_array, $general_linkboxes, $bodyClass;
    if ($linkbox_array == $general_linkboxes && $bodyClass == "withSidebar") {
...
```

I've edited this answer to include the = -> == fix on $bodyClass

Comment: This got it working! Thanks! So let's see if I understand this: any variable I declare outside of a function needs to be set as a global within the function so that the function can pull it in? Otherwise the variable is not set? I thought the variable being on the same page, and above the function, would be enough for the function to recognize it.

Comment: A function only has access to variables that are either passed to it as parameters, or declared inside it. This is called Scope. To access a global variable inside a function, that variable must be within the function's Scope. To get it there you need to either pass it as a parameter, or use the global $varname line to bring it into scope. The problem with doing this is that you can accidentally change things in a way you don't want to if you change the value of that variable, so you need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Your if conditional just needs a bit of refactoring:

```
if(($linkbox_array == $general_linkboxes) && ($bodyClass == "withSidebar")) {}
```

A single '=' is an assignment operation and will always evaluate to true.

A == is the conditional equals operation you were looking for.

Furthermore if you are checking for array equality and order matters to you then you should use the '===' operator which checks not just for the same elements but also the same order

Lastly you have a scoping issue - if your linkbox array is evaluating as equal to a null variable then it hasn't been defined. You can use the [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) operation to check this. If the array is defined outside the function then you should pass it to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you set `$linkbox_array` outside of your function, then your function doesn't knoew it, unless you ...

```
function display_linkboxes($array) {
     global $linkbox_array; // <------ now the variable exists within the function.
     if ($linkbox_array == $askjfdalfjk) {
         foreach ($array as $linkbox) {
             echo $linkbox;
         }
     }
 }
```

Same with `$bodyClass`